# Calling one query from a different query in access

Tags: ms-access

Let's say I have 3 queries:

- Query1
- Query2
- Query3

And I want to run them all by running a single query QueryRunAll.  How can I run Query1, Query2, and Query3 within QueryRunAll?

Thanks much!

Comment: What do you mean by "run all" ? Are these action queries ? Or SELECT queries that you want to open ? Or are these queries dependant of each other ?

Comment: Are they `SELECT` queries that you just want returned in one recordset?

Comment: I know you can do a select from an access query, but I just want to run them.  These are all ACTION queries (INSERT).  Hope that provides more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Query1`, `Query2`, and `Query3` are all `INSERT` queries, the only way you could run them all from a single query, `QueryRunAll`, is with a user defined function.

If you will be running `QueryRunAll` from inside an Access session, you could use this as its SQL:

```
SELECT Runall() AS successful;
```

However if you intend to run `QueryRunAll` from outside an Access session, it can't use a UDF, so you won't be able to have one query run 3 action queries.

```
Public Function Runall() As String
    Dim blnReturn As Boolean
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Execute "Query1", dbFailOnError
    db.Execute "Query2", dbFailOnError
    db.Execute "Query3", dbFailOnError
    blnReturn = True
    Set db = Nothing

ExitHere:
    Set db = Nothing
    Runall = blnReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    ' do more here if desired
    GoTo ExitHere
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access (*at least 2003*) does allow the following syntax for queries which would allow you to run multiple queries together:

```
SELECT Query1.col1, Query2.col2, Query3.col1
FROM Query1, Query2, Query3
```

or for `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (col1, col2,...)
SELECT Query1.col1, Query2.col2
FROM Query1, Query2, Query3
```